# Syntax error - Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

This is the query I am using:

```
$q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder("SELECT e FROM ActionModule\Action e JOIN e.type t WHERE t.id IN (:ids)");
```

I have tried every parameter assigning option:

- :ids
- ?1
- implode(',', $ids)
- ?ids

And always get:

> Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
>
> [Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable
>   | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got end
>   of string

Thanks a lot in advance

**EDIT:**

I've dumped `$q->getQuery()->getDql()` and got:
`"SELECT" (6)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`createQueryBuilder`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L349) doesn't accept any arguments and its purpose is creating queries using the builder methods, not DQL.

What you need is [`createQuery`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php#L289).

```
$q = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery("SELECT e FROM ActionModule\Action e JOIN e.type t WHERE t.id IN (:ids)");
```